Rename duplicated column in Pandas
I have a Pandas dataframe with two columns with the same name and I want to rename one of them. I know the index of each one but I haven't found a way to rename a column by index, and all the ways I have found involve to get the name of the column based on the index which wouldn't work for me since that would return two indexes.
Thanks

probably simplest to automatically deduplicate them (and rename afterwards if desired): https://stackoverflow.com/a/71700612/13138364

Example
plz provide minimal-reproducible-example when ask.
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'A'])

df
   A  B  A
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

Code
When you konw iloc, you can handle it by converting it to a list. Of course, the result needs to set to columns.
cols = df.columns.tolist()
idx = 2
cols[idx] = 'new'
out = df.set_axis(cols, axis=1)

out
   A  B  new
0  1  2    3
1  4  5    6
2  7  8    9


Here is a very basic way:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([ [1,2,3], [2,1,4], [5,3,4]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col1'])

   Col1 Col2 Col1
0   1    2    3
1   2    1    4
2   5    3    4

df.columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3']

   Col1 Col2 Col3
0   1    2   3
1   2    1   4
2   5    3   4

